# Difference between two txt files written by php script

Tags: php, sorting

I have build this script that should save only unique lines, in this case url's. One url per line into a .txt file.

On my form I have only one value which is "url" from input name="url".

Script works, get's the value, checks if unique or not, writes into constant file , then I applied sorting from A to Z and writes sorted output into a new temp file. Here are my 3 things that I would like to ask for, any help appreciated:

1. I'm not sure if this is correct approach to write sorting into new file or is it possible to re-write the original file
2. Temp file is written with empty lines in between lines with values. Can't figure it out from where empty lines are coming from.
3. Last bit is that temp file is always one line less than constant file.

   ```
   <?php

   // config
   $url = $_GET['url'];
   $n = "\n";
   $data = $url . $n;
   $file = "datatest.txt"; // constant file
   $file2 = "datatest2.txt"; // temp file

   // check for duplicates & add new value if unique
   $unique_data = file_get_contents($file);
   if(strpos($unique_data, $data) === false){
   $fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("Can't open the file");

   // chmod (optional)
   chmod($file,0666);
   chmod($file2,0666);

   // sort
   $lines = file($file);
   sort($lines);

   // write to original
   $record = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

   // write to temp
   $record2 = file_put_contents("$file2", implode("\n", $lines));

   }

   // testing echo the results
   if (empty($record)){
   echo "data already exists </br></br>";
   }else{
   echo $record . " bytes written to file </br></br>";
   echo $record2 . " bytes written to file2 </br></br>";
   }

   // display all (change file if needed)
   $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
   $pageText = fread($fh, 25000);

   echo nl2br($pageText);

   ?>
   ```

Any input appreciated.

edit:

With @Barmar help I managed to eliminate points 2 & 3.

```
<?php

// config
$url = $_GET['url'];
$n = "\n";
$data = $url . $n;
$file = "temp.txt"; // temp file in local folder
$file2 = "constant.txt"; // constant counterpart file

// check for duplicates & add new value if unique
$unique_data = file_get_contents($file);
if(strpos($unique_data, $data) === false){

$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("Can't open the file");

// chmod (optional)
chmod($file,0666);
chmod($file2,0666);

// write to original
$record = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

// sort
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
sort($lines);

// write to temp
$record2 = file_put_contents($file2, implode("\n", $lines), LOCK_EX);

}

// testing echo the results
if (empty($record)){
echo "data already exists </br></br>";
}else{
echo $record . " bytes written to file </br></br>";
echo $record2 . " bytes written to file2 </br></br>";
}

// display all (change file if needed)
$fh = fopen($file2, 'r');
$pageText = fread($fh, 25000);

echo nl2br($pageText);

?>
```

Still can't figure it out how to use only one file instead. @Barmar, I've tried to use your "in_array" but it's giving me an error.

Comment: this screams, "use a database"

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to rewrite the original file?

Comment: @rtfm this script is only a part of bigger picture, with multiple mysql databases, But this one needs to be done with .txt files. Ready .txt files are imported via (manually & cron) into appropriate mysql db's.

Comment: even more reason to leverage the power of a db, over this approach

Comment: @rtfm, with all due respect but I'm asking reg. .txt files solution and not if should I use mysql or other type of db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it's possible to rewrite the original file. Just use a single file that's always sorted:

   ```
   $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
   if (in_array($url, $lines)) {
       $lines[] = $url;
       sort($lines);
       file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $lines) . "\n");
   }
   ```
2. The empty lines are from `implode("\n", $lines)`, because the strings in `$lines` already end with newline. So you're adding a second newline between them. In my code above I used `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to prevent it from including them in the strings.
3. I suspect this has something to do with the newlines, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: thx, I will give it a try and will let you know tomorrow, it's late here for me for more writing. btw. is it $in_array or should be in_array ? Also I've managed to solve point number 3. I've change code order and put // sort before //write temp file but //after write of constant file. And You are also right about the point number 2. "\n". Fixed as well.